# What does the information_schema database represent?

Tags: information-schema, mysql5

I have one database in mysql.

But when i log into phpMyAdmin , it shows another database called information_schema.

Is that database always present with one database?

I mean to say is there a copy of information_schema for every database present in mysql or is there one database called inforemation_schema per mysql server?

If i modify this information_schema database how will that affect my current database?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can think of information_schema as a "master database" that holds details about all the other databases on the server such as the names and types of tables, columns and users.

#### What is information_schema?

From [the reference documentation:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html)

> INFORMATION_SCHEMA provides access to
>   database metadata.
>
> Metadata is data about the data, such
>   as the name of a database or table,
>   the data type of a column, or access
>   privileges. Other terms that sometimes
>   are used for this information are data
>   dictionary and system catalog.
>
> INFORMATION_SCHEMA is the information
>   database, the place that stores
>   information about all the other
>   databases that the MySQL server
>   maintains. Inside INFORMATION_SCHEMA
>   there are several read-only tables.
>   They are actually views, not base
>   tables, so there are no files
>   associated with them.

#### What is stored in information_schema?

You can see the kinds of things stored in information_schema, and the way in which they are organised, by viewing [this diagram](http://www.xcdsql.org/Misc/MySQL_INFORMATION_SCHEMA.html) (for MySQL 5.0) or [this diagram](http://www.xcdsql.org/MySQL/information_schema/5.1/MySQL_5_1_INFORMATION_SCHEMA.html) (for MySQL 5.1).

#### What happens if I modify information_schema?

In reality, information_schema is a collection of read-only views. As such, it should be impossible to modify it and do any damage. However, [the MySQL FAQ on this topic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-information-schema.html) has this to say:

> 23.7.3: Can I add to or otherwise modify the tables found in the
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA database?
>
> No.
>   Since applications may rely on a
>   certain standard structure, this
>   should not be modified. For this
>   reason, we cannot support bugs or
>   other issues which result from
>   modifying INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables or
>   data.

This implies that if you do find yourself able to modify information_schema (which should be impossible, and is in MySQL, but other vendor implementations of SQL might allow it) you should at the very least choose not to. If you *could* damage/modify information_schema you'd be damaging the actual structure (e.g. table names, column types) of your other databases.

#### Does every user have their own copy of information_schema?

Each user can see information_schema that pertains to the tables and databases they have access to. Some users with heavily limited rights will still see information_schema but will see only NULL values for any information_schema queries.  However, it is important to remember that information_schema is not an actual database, but simply a convenient way SQL provides so that you can select information about your database(s) and table(s).

From [the reference documentation:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html)

> Each MySQL user has the right to
>   access these tables, but can see only
>   the rows in the tables that correspond
>   to objects for which the user has the
>   proper access privileges. In some
>   cases (for example, the
>   ROUTINE_DEFINITION column in the
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES table),
>   users who have insufficient privileges
>   will see NULL.

#### Where can I find more information?

- The MySQL Reference Manual article on information_schema (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html)
- The MySQL FAQ article on information_schema (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-information-schema.html)

Comment: But if that is sensitive data then why as a normal user i can see that dtabase at all. it sholuld be hidden by default. Isn't it the security flaw

Comment: You're not a normal user, I imagine you created your own database so that makes you a server admin. You're probably logged in as the default root user when using phpMyAdmin right?

Comment: It also doesn't hold the data of your other databases, just the structure, in case that needed clarifying.

Comment: I looged as root but when i also looged as normal user without any special previleges , i can still see information_schema. I got some databse from one hosting company and they gave me my db details . When i logged in phpmyadmin i can also see my database as well as information_schema. Then i thought may be it belong to every user

Comment: Answer updated. Basic summary: every user can see information_schema relevant to the stuff they can access. Please let me know if you have further questions, or accept this answer if it answers your question.

Comment: since it is read-only database,it want to know where it is stored,I know it is a virtual table,but the question is from where `information_schmea` is stored.